# macOS mouse behaviour from a windows user

Tags: macos, window-focus

I have bought myself a mac, and coming from 20 years of windows use, some things i am finding quite jarring... but don't know the 'terms' to search online in order to see if anyone has really done anything about it.

In Windows 10 for example, lets say you have two applications open (maybe on two monitors), and you you are interacting with one of them. For complete clarity, let's just say you are writing a word document.

Then, in another window you have maybe your email open, or some music playing.. another application on another monitor... fairly normal right?

Ok, so my main focus is my document editor, and i'm writing away.. and a song comes on that i don't much fancy.. i want to click "next track", and skip it.

On windows... i mouse over to the music application, and can click the "next track" in one mouse click.

On macOS... my first click is WASTED bring the window in to focus... and the second click actually allows me to choose "next track", it's utterly infuriating!!

I have googled for for this, and the closest i come up with is "focus follows mouse" ... but i don't think that's correct.

Can someone help me stay sane?? :(

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269622/macos-windows-requiring-an-explicit-click-to-make-active-before-ui-elements-ins

Comment: heh, i literally just found this page via googly woogly

Comment: Protip from someone who switches between various OSes quite a bit: You'll easily learn to "code-switch" between the different OSes if you just leave them at their defaults and quit trying to tweak them all to act like the first one you happened to learn. You can waste a lot of time trying to tweak everything, or you can just let your amazing subconscious mind handle it all for you. I highly recommend the latter approach.